# Why does passing an array to another method change the original array?

Tags: java, arrays

In the following code, calling swapBig(a,some number,somenumber), where a is an array, is copied to bleh[] in swapBig(). When values in bleh[] are swapped, the corresponding values in a[] are also changed. Why does this happen, and how would I write the code so that only bleh[] is modified and not the original a[]? Thanks so much!

```
public static void swapBig(String bleh[], int to, int from){ //switches data
    //Actually performing the swaps
    String temp;
    temp = bleh[to];
    bleh[to] = bleh[from];
    bleh[from] = temp;
}
public static void quickSort(String a[], String b[], String c[], String d[],
String e[],String f[], int from, int to){
    //performing the quickSort
    if (from >= to) return;
    int p = (from + to) / 2;
    int i = from;
    int j = to;
    while (i <= j){
        if (a[i].compareTo(a[p]) <= 0)
            i++;
        else if (a[j].compareTo(a[p]) >= 0)
            j--;
        else{
            swapBig(a, i, j);
            swapBig(b, i, j);
            swapBig(c, i, j);
            swapBig(d, i, j);
            swapBig(e, i, j);
            swapBig(f, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (p<j){
        swapBig(a, p, j);
        swapBig(b, p, j);
        swapBig(c, p, j);
        swapBig(d, p, j);
        swapBig(e, p, j);
        swapBig(f, p, j);
        p = j;
    }else if (p>i){
        swapBig(a, p, i);
        swapBig(b, p, i);
        swapBig(c, p, i);
        swapBig(d, p, i);
        swapBig(e, p, i);
        swapBig(f, p, i);
        p = i;
    }
    quickSort(a, b, c, d,e,f, from, p-1);
    quickSort(a, b, c, d,e,f, p + 1, to);
}

public static void main (String args [])
{
    //Asking for options (what to sort by/search for)
    System.out.println("Sort or Search?");
    String look = promptFor.nextLine();
    if (look.equalsIgnoreCase("Sort")){
    System.out.println("Sort by First, Last, Instrument, Instrument Family, 
    Special Title, or University:");
    String toSortBy = promptFor.nextLine();
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("First"))
        quickSort(fname,lname,inst,instFam,title,uni,0,9);
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("Last"))
        quickSort(lname,fname,inst,instFam,title,uni,0,9);
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("Instrument"))
        quickSort(inst,lname,fname,instFam,title,uni,0,9);
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("Instrument Family"))
        quickSort(instFam,lname,inst,fname,title,uni,0,9);
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("Special Title"))
        quickSort(title,lname,inst,instFam,uni,fname,0,9);
    if (toSortBy.equalsIgnoreCase("University"))
        quickSort(uni,lname,inst,instFam,title,fname,0,9);
    print();
    main(null);     }
    else if (look.equalsIgnoreCase("Search")) {
    System.out.println("Which last name do you wish to search for?");
        searchFor(promptFor.nextLine());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Command Not Recognized\n");
        main(null);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: In Java, method parameters are by reference, not by value, which means you pass the reference to the object, not a copy of the object. Note that primitives are passed by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple enough.

The values of the arrays are swapped, because you passed the array to the swapping function, and in Java, parameters are passed by reference.

To avoid this.

```
String[] tempArray = a.clone();
swapBig(tempArray, i, j); //This will not change the values in a, but tempArray.
```

Answer (score 6):

you are passing a reference to the array, not a copy of it.

Answer (score 2):

Variable `bleh` is copied the value of variable `a` so actually `bleh` is pointing to actual object and if you modify with `bleh` this will change actual object this is because of java supports pass by value.

You can get the desired result if you clone it before pass.

Answer (score 1):

because you have passed the reference of the object and any operation with this reference will modify the main object

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a copy of the array use the arrayVar.clone() method, System.arraycopy(), or Array.copyOf().

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a method, java does not create a duplicate of the array X to that method. It passes the reference to array X.

Example:

```
public void swap(Color a, Color b) {
    Color temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

This has no effect. But,

```
.
.
.
   swap(x, y);
}

public void swap(Color[] a, Color[] b) {
   Color temp = a[0];
   a[0] = b[0];
   b[0] = temp;
}
```

this will swap the 1st value of x[] with the first value of y[].